# Copy array with `ToArray` Method

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Ok, maybe I'm just lazy but this might be a cool question to have on the interwebs.

I know that `Buffer.BlockCopy(...)` is faster than `Array.Copy(...)` when working with `byte[]`. I was about to write a `CloneBuffer` helper that would create an array the same size as a source array then copy the source array into it using `Buffer.BlockCopy(...)` when I instead wrote:

```
public void Send(byte[] data) {
    // Copy caller-provided buffer
    var buf = data.ToArray();

    // Start async send here and return immediately
}
```

Does anyone know if the `ToArray()` method special-cased for `byte[]` or if this is going to be slower than `BlockCopy`?

Comment: I would doubt it, but you can look at the source code and see for yourself if you're curious.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to wrap `Buffer.BlockCopy` in the first place?

Comment: @EdS. In quite a few places in my code I new up a new `byte[]` of the length of the source, then copy the source to the new array. It's just a DRY function so I don't have to write the 3 lines of code everywhere I need to copy a buffer.

Answer (score 7):

You can look into the Microsoft .NET assemblies using a *reflector program*, such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net).

This tells me that the implementation of `System.Linq.Enumerable::ToArray()` is:

```
public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    // ...
    return new Buffer<TSource>(source).ToArray();
}
```

And the constructor of the internal struct `Buffer<T>` does:

- If the source enumerable implements `ICollection<T>`, then:

  - allocate an array of [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec.aspx) elements, and
  - use [`CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw.aspx) to copy the collection into the array.
- Otherwise:

  - allocate an array of 4 elements, and
  - start enumerating the IEnumerable, storing each value in the array.
  - Is the array too small?

    - Create a new array that has twice the size of the old one,
    - and copy the old array's content into the new one,
    - then use the new array instead, and continue.

And `Buffer<T>.ToArray()` simply returns the inner array if its size matches the number of elements in it; otherwise copies the inner array to a new array with the exact size.

Note that this `Buffer<T>` class is internal and not related to the `Buffer` class you mentioned.

All copying is done using [`Array.Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx).

So, to conclude: all copying is done using `Array.Copy()` and there is no optimization for byte arrays. But I don't know whether it is slower than [`Buffer.BlockCopy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx). The only way to know is to measure.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the info. If I remember, the `Array.Copy()` wasn't _that_ much slower, so this will probably work fine for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is going to be slower.

When you look at the [documentation for the System.Array methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array_methods.aspx), there is no definition for `System.Array.ToArray()`. In fact, looking at the inheritance/interface tree, it's all the way we have to go back all the way to `[IEnumerable.ToArray()][2]` before we find this method. Since this was implemented with only the features of IEnumerable to work with, it can't know the size of the resulting array when it begins executing. Instead, it uses a doubling algorithm to build up the array as it runs. So you might end up creating and throwing away several arrays over the course of making the copy, and copying those initial items several time in the course of destroying/recreating each intermediate buffer.

If you want a simpler, naive implementation, at least look at [`Array.CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx). And remember: I said, "If".

Comment: This is not correct. Why do you assume it can only be implemented with the features of `IEnumerable`? It _does_ know the size of the resulting array when it begins executing, if the enumerable implements `ICollection<T>`. That's an optimization.